# Step function computational limitations

Tags: neural-network

What are the limits on step functions as activation functions for neural networks?

I've heard nonlinear functions are needed for universality, but where do step functions stand in this?  Are they as limited as linear activation functions?  Would they classify as linear?

Comment: A limitation with the step function: it isn't differentiable, which means you can't propagate the deltas in the backpropagation algorithm. ie: backpropagation does not support the step function activation function.

Comment: Thanks, but besides training issues, are there any limitations on what such networks can compute?

Comment: I mean are multilayer networks of these essentially universal, or not?

Comment: The Unit step, or "thresholding", activation function is not linear. It belongs to the same class of nonlinear transformation functions as the sigmoid function